# Creating spotlight in OpenGL scene

Tags: c++, opengl, lighting, vertex-shader

I'm studying `OpenGL` and trying to create a spot light at my application. The code that I'm using for my `#vertex-shader` is shown below:

```
    #:vertex-shader #{
        #version 150 core
            in vec3 in_pos;
            in vec2 in_tc;
            out vec2 tc;

            glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 20.0f);
            GLfloat spot_direction[] = { -1.0, -1.0, 0.0 };
            glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, spot_direction);

            glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);


            void main() {

                vec4 pos= vec4(vec3(1.0)*in_pos - vec3(1.0), 1.0);
                pos.z=0.0;
                gl_Position =   pos;
                tc = in_tc;
            }
}
```

The thing is, every time I'm trying to run the code an Error that says:

```
Type: other, Source: api, ID: 131169, Severity: low
Message: Framebuffer detailed info: The driver allocated storage for renderbuffer 1.
 len = 157, written = 0
failed to compile vertex shader of deferred: directional
info log for shader deferred: directional
vertex info log for shader deferred: directional:
ERROR: Unbound variable: when
```

Specifications:

```
Renderer: GeForce GTX 580/PCIe/SSE2
Version: 3.3.0 NVIDIA 319.17
GLSL: 3.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
Status: Using GLEW 1.9.0
1024 x 768
OS: Linux debian
```

I guess to create this spotlight is pretty much simple, but since I'm really new to `OpenGL` I don't have a clue how to do it until now, even reading sources like:

http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter05.html#name3

Read also in some place that light spots can get really hard to understand, but I cant avoid this step right now since I'm following my lecture schedule. Could anybody help me?

Comment: GL functions in a shader? That's just horrible. Why do you do this? Do you pre-process that source somehow? Also, you're using a GLSL 150 shader and still go for legacy GL? Why?

Comment: You are asking me a bunch of questions that I dont have knowledge to argue, instead of making so many questions, you could make me understand whats going on..

Comment: See datenwolf's answer. That's spot on.

Comment: If you don't understand @thokra questions, then you should probably star reading/learning some more, a lot more, about OpenGL before you start programming with it.

Comment: Sometimes I just hate how some people deal with noob  questions here, they are really rude and dont think twice as they were starters someday before vote it down and close. This should stay open to show novices how to deal with the hard path of reading tutorials. And with all respect, I only got 2 weeks of lecture, Im dealing with my professor schedule and also running against time to learn concepts that I dont get inside my class. Wished people knew what this means.

Comment: If you're referring to me, my intent wasn't to be rude - sometimes certain things you see just hurt. :) Actually, just like datenwolf, it is beyond me, how you even got the idea to put regular GL functions *inside* a shader. If you have seen this somehwere, even if it's your professor's slides, please tell me where so I can yell at them instead of you. And trust me, I know what it means, as do probably many people around here - you aren't the only one with academic experience.

Comment: I will keep the hard work to not do those sort of mistake again, thanks

Comment: I know it looks beyond weird, but there are effects frameworks where you can mix pseudo-API state calls with shader instructions. Not quite the same way it is done here, but they basically tell the shader manager / batch processor what states an effect needs... people just starting out may come across these things from time to time and misunderstand what is actually going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You completely, totally misunderstood what shaders do. First of all you're declaring function calls in the global scope, which is disallowed anyway. And then, for some reason I cannot fathom you try to call deprecated, old style, fixed function OpenGL state setter functions in the shader. This is not how it works.

I suggest you head to a decent OpenGL tutorial, and work through it **from the beginning** without skipping things. I suggest http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut

Comment: I appreciate your answer man, will accept in 5 minutes and start to do the dirty work right now. thanks

Comment: Coming by once again to say thank you for the link you gave me. This book is really awesome and catchs basic concepts which I already knew but its always good to refresh. thank you